# Ransack Search model attributes from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I have a Rails App going here and I am building ransack into it.

I Have Devise installed, but really have no use for a user index page, instead I have a controller named MemberListController with directory method in it and a directory page that links to it. This is where I want my admin users to view the membership directory. (see below for controller)

```
MemberListController.rb

class MemberListController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

      def directory
        @users = User.all
        @q = User.ransack(params[:q])
        @user = @q.result(distinct: true)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.xlsx
        end

      end

    end
```

I built in the following search form to the directory page:

```
   <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :f_name_or_l_name_or_email_or_business_name %>
      <%= f.search_field :f_name_or_l_name_or_email_or_business_name %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

When I submit the form from the directory page (where i want the results to be displayed.. I get the following error:

```
UsersController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

Im not sure why i twats a user controller or index action as everything is managed through the directory controller.

Please help not sure where I'm going wrong with this.. is there a way to display this out side of the users controller like ransack wants to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ransack is smart enough to infer `form_url` from ransack search object.

So, if you don't pass any `url` option to ransack `search_form_for`  it will submit the form to index action of the entity for which ransack search form is built.

So, you have to change your view logic to the following code-

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: member_lists_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :f_name_or_l_name_or_email_or_business_name %>
  <%= f.search_field :f_name_or_l_name_or_email_or_business_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[Here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), you can read more about ransack.